# Hide On-Screen Keyboard when tapping outside of the Text Field (Anywhere on the screen) in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, keyboard, dart, flutter

I came across an issue where its getting hard for me to hide the on screen keyboard whenever I tap anywhere on the screen (if the keyboard is opened) (Just like what happens in native android app where the keyboard hides automatically when tapping anywhere on the screen).
Any kind of assistance would be helpful.

Comment: Very strange situation here, I just found a answer for you in the duplicated question !

Comment: Asked this because the previous question wasn’t about hiding keyboard on tapping anywhere and I’ve seen people in my office struggling to find an answer.